# Incorrect and weird unix time conversion to datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For some weird reason I cannot convert a column of a dataframe with unix format to a standard datetime format:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"f1":[1420059600, 1420066800], "f2":["A", "B"]})
>>> format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"
>>> pd.to_datetime(df["f1"], errors='coerce', origin="unix", format=format)
0   NaT
1   NaT
Name: f1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

if I do not provide a format argument I get

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df["f1"], errors='coerce', origin="unix")
0   1970-01-01 00:00:01.420059600
1   1970-01-01 00:00:01.420066800
Name: f1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

With some unclear ending at the end.

I expect the output to be:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df["f1"], errors='coerce', origin="unix")
0   12/31/2014 21:00:00
1   12/31/2014 23:00:00
Name: f1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Thank you!

Pandas 1.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `unit = s`. I have not formatted the output, you can format it as you wish. One suggestion. don't use name 'format' for format. use something else that is not a standard

```
pd.to_datetime(df["f1"], errors='coerce', unit ='s')
```

**Output**

```
0   2014-12-31 21:00:00
1   2014-12-31 23:00:00
```